# overriding default format when printing a list of datetime objects

Tags: python, printing, formatting, python-3.x

I have (in Python 3):

```
print('event {} happened on these dates: {}'.format(event_name, date_list))
```

My `date_list` is a list of `datetime.date` objects. I would like to change the format from:

> event A happened on [datetime.date(2011, 5, 31), datetime.date(2011,
>   6, 15)]

to

> event A happened on [2011-05-31, 2011-06-15]

What's the best way to achieve that? I was hoping I could keep using the `format()` function, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Printing a list gives the `repr` of the items inside the list. 
To get the `str` representation of the items, you have to explicitly call `str` on the items:

```
In [6]: import datetime as dt

In [7]: date_list = [dt.date(2011, 5, 31), dt.date(2011, 6, 15)]

In [8]: print('[{}]'.format(', '.join(map(str,date_list))))
[2011-05-31, 2011-06-15]
```

Comment: Got it... it's a lot of repetitive `join` calls though. Is it a good idea to subclass `datetime.date` to override `__repr__` so it simply calls `__str__`?

Comment: It is actually only one `join` call, though (possibly) many `str` calls. Subclassing `datetime.date` so `__repr__` returns `str(self)` is possible but only do it if you like the simpler syntax, not for speed. In fact, using a subclass would be slower, since every `__repr__` call would make a `str` call. In effect, you would be making just as many `str` calls as above, plus the overhead of an equal number of `__repr__` calls. Anyway, don't worry about speed until you've profiled and identified the major bottlenecks. I doubt it will be here.

Comment: I'm sorry I did mean "repetitive" in the sense of writing the code, not execution :) I have many places where I print a list of dates... So it seems that for my purposes, it's not too bad to subclass. Thanks!