# How to format the datetime object in list with strftime while leaving following numbers unaffected

Tags: python, list, datetime

I have a typical `list` of data, where the first item is a datetime object, and the following items are data corresponding to the date and time. I would like to print and format the `datetime` object. I don't want the `str` representation of the `datetime`, but rather, I would like to choose the formatting via `strftime` or something similar.

I have tried

```
 print('{}'.format(', '.join(map(str,row))))
```

and it works ok, but I really don't want that format (from [overriding default format when printing a list of datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052433/overriding-default-format-when-printing-a-list-of-datetime-objects)).

I know how to use `strftime`, but I don't know how to call it on the data in the `list`. It seems like there should be an easy way to do this. When searching for how to perform this, results are either about `strftime` or using `str` in a `list` as above, so I have not been able to find what I am trying to do.

Comment: So why is this downvoted?  I spent 2 hours looking this up beforehand.  As described, the results were not what I was looking for because the common answer was for a different question.  No one seems to care to answer the question and the only person who did got downvotes because the solution for my non-production code is "unacceptable for production".  If you are going to take the time to downvote, please add something useful to the conversation, such as a request for clarification.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This will leave the non-`datetime` objects alone (I assume they're strings - if not, use `else str(item)` instead of `else item`). It uses a ternary `if..else` to look at each item in the `row`.

```
print(', '.join(datetime.datetime.strftime(item, '%Y%m%d') if type(item) == datetime.datetime else item for item in row))
```

The `format()` doesn't seem necessary, since you're only printing one item and not doing any formatting.

Comment: It works!  I had to substitute 'else str(item)' instead of 'else item' to format my doubles but this is what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Quirky, thus unacceptable for production (as well as a good example).

Comment: @ivan, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Quirky = behaviour is inconsistent and depends on many random factors. That likely results in side-effects and general unreliability.

Comment: 1)Converts all dates rather that the first (discarding the time part btw); 2) Doesn't enforce the input format stated by the OP (date+a number of additional fields), thus non-conforming input will slip; 3) `datetime.datetime` is required strictly when other types will do as well.

Comment: I am using this in a print function for a data inside an object that has a well defined format. For me, this single line is working.  I could have written a method to handle this, but I think this one line solution is much cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

```
print ", ".join((row[0].strftime('%Y%m%d'),)+tuple(str(i) for i in row[1:]))
```

I have defined this line as `def print_row(row):` for the following examples.

```
In [25]: print_row( (datetime.datetime(2010,12,02),"foo",1.23e3,-1000,
         datetime.date(2012,02,12)) )
20101202, foo, 1230.0, -1000, 2012-02-12

In [24]: print_row((datetime.date(2012,12,02),))
20121202

In [27]: print_row(())
<stacktrace>
IndexError: tuple index out of range

In [29]: print_row((1000,))
<stacktrace>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: This function could produce wrong results if it's passed a `list` subclass with a custom `__getitem__`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 redefining `__getitem__` for an indexed sequence while not redefining `__iter__` correspondingly stops an object from acting like an indexed sequence (violates `seq[i]==list(iter(seq))[i]`).